# Handle AMFPHP execution error (not exception)

Tags: flash, cakephp, exception, amf, amfphp

We use *CakeAMF*. It handles exceptions in a code gracefully and returns `FaultEvent` to flash side. But, if some PHP error (Fatal Error) will occur - it is not possible to handle this from client side - we receive only error 500 without any explanation. In request parser (like `Service Capture` or `Charles` i see HTML text about error description, which is written by *CakePHP*).

Is there any way to catch and process this errors in AMF classes and return `FaultEvent`, instead of Cake HTML text?

Comment: Have you looked at the error handling documentation? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

you can try setting a custom error handler that can turn it into an exception.
There's a plugin for that in AmfPHP 2.0, but as I recall CakeAMF is still using 1.9 so you'll have to code it yourself

try something along the lines of
        set_error_handler('custom_warning_handler');

function custom_warning_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
    throw new Exception("$errstr . \n
file:  $errfile \n
line: $errline \n
context: " . print_r($errcontext, true), $errno);
}